# Saving files in new name highlight incorrect field

Tags: files

Every time I save a already saved file under new name (Save As), the old name is highlited in the Name field, so I start typing the name I want. But what happens is it tries to find a file matching what I tpye. A different field is selected, but I'm fooled into thinking the name field is selected because it's highlited.

Answer (score 3):

In this case the highlight indicates where to enter the name, not the selected field.